# Node.js - Files Uploaded to an S3 bucket from another S3 bucket doesn't display on page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I'm copying image files from an AWS S3 bucket to another S3 bucket using a Node.js program. Copied image files will be displayed on a React.js page.

The files did get copied and I can see them in S3 listing of the destination bucket. However, when same image file is displayed on the React page, it doesn't display it. Already existing files get displayed on the page without any issue.

To me, it seems like a permission issue. I've read about `ACL` and have tried `ACL: "public-read"` (which gives unable to upload file: AccessDenied: Access Denied) and `ACL: "private"` (file gets uploaded, but doesn't displayed on the page).

I'm running a node cli that copies/upload S3 files from one bucket into another. Here is a code segment:

```
async function createS3(fileName) {
      const params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET_DEST,
        CopySource: "/" + BUCKET_SRC + "/" + fileName,
        Key: fileName,
        //ACL: "public-read",
        //ACL: "private",
      };
      const headParams = {
        Bucket: BUCKET_DEST,
        Key: fileName,
      };
    
      try {
        await s3.headObject(headParams).promise();
      } catch (ex) {
    
        const sourceParams = {
          Bucket: BUCKET_SRC,
          Key: fileName,
        };
    
        const destinationParams = {
          Bucket: BUCKET_DEST,
          Key: fileName,
          //ACL: "public-read",
          //ACL: "private",
        };
    
        const objectStream = s3_src.getObject(sourceParams).createReadStream();
        const upload = s3_dest.upload({
          ...destinationParams,
          Body: objectStream,
        });
    
        try {
          await upload.promise();
        } catch (e) {
          logger.log("error", `unable to upload file: ${e}`);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: How are you using image from S3 to your webpage? is your bucket public? check the `filename` or `path` of the image after copying to the `bucket`

Comment: `filename` and `path` are correct and existing files in the destination bucket gets displayed correctly.

Comment: since you are hosting SPA using the bucket, bucket is `public` right ? Can you refer [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-public-access-acl/)